# How to delete everything before a certain character with characters split into groups

Tags: java, regex, string

So I have a Java input in the form

```
s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,...,sn
```

Where I have n characters separated by a comma. I want to split them at a certain point and have only the characters with a greater index left in my string.
Let's assume this code

```
String s = "a,bn,c,st1,d,kr332,23,b4,46"
```

I would like to split it, let's say after the third sign, so at c.
I want the string that's left to be

```
s="st1,d,kr332,23,b4,46"
```

I have come up with one method but it seems quite primitive

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
s="";
```

Now I would have a list of Strings and I could iterate through them like

```
for(int i=(number where i want to cut off); i<list.size(); i++){
s+=list.get(i);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like you already have tagged this as regex.  You can do this with regex in java.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/    Give it a try, and if you get stumped, ask another question.

Comment: Why do you need to split them to just end up joining the tokens back in? You could just find the desired pattern position and then substring from there. For instance, finding the index of ",c,".

Comment: Also, just so you are aware, Strings are immutable in Java, so you can't technically "delete" the start of the string.  You'll end up with a new String object that contains what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This task doesn't require any regex.

```
String s = "a,bn,c,st1,d,kr332,23,b4,46";
String find = ",c,";

String r = s.substring(s.indexOf(find)+find.length()); // st1,d,kr332,23,b4,46
```

**EDIT:**

```
As per comments you can use this to remove everything upto 3rd comma:

String r = s.replaceFirst("([^,]*,){3}", "")
```

Comment: I think OP was using `,c,` as an example, and really wants to get everything after the *3rd* `,`.  That still should be doable in a similar fashion, and I may have been mistaken.

Comment: Yes, the thing that @Stan is saying is true. Is there any way to get anything after the n-th member?

Answer (score 2):

Using JDK 8, and supposing your are searching tokens by the position, this ought to work:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
//...

int pos = 3;
String s = "a,bn,c,st1,d,kr332,23,b4,46";

String[] tokens = s.split(",")  ;
if(tokens.length > pos){
   String rejoined = stream(tokens, pos, tokens.length).collect(joining(","));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
String s = "a,bn,c,st1,d,kr332,23,b4,46";
String search = "c";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));

String output = StringUtils.join(list.subList(list.indexOf(search) + 1, list.size()), ",");
```

Output:

```
st1,d,kr332,23,b4,46
```

Comment: This works, but I wonder how this would hold up if OP is using this on really large files, or needs it to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend RegEx..but since it was part of your question and I want to get faster at writing expressions, I whipped this up:

```
(?:\w+,){3}(.*)
```

This will match (but not capture) 3 sets of 1+ word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) followed by a comma.  Then we will match and capture everything else in the string.

See example here: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iC3kI7)

---

Additionally, you can just match the *first* 3 sets of 1+ word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) followed by a comma:

```
^(\w+,){3}
```

And then use Java to replace this match with an empty string: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/pV6wS2)